# Flickity options groupcells and wraparound and uneven amount of cells

Tags: javascript, html, css, flickity

I'm trying to create an infinite slider that always shows two slides. 
The Flickity slider has two options: groupcells and wrap around.

The problem is that with an uneven amount of cells lets say five cells, the fifth cell will be alone. So the grouping will be as followed: [1, 2] [3, 4] [5]. 
I would like the grouping to be [1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 1] [2, 3] [4, 5] [1, 2].

One idea I had was to duplicate the HTML for the cells so that instead of 5 cells you have 10 and therefor even number.

If anyone has a better idea I would like to know.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZoNyy) of the problem.

```
<!-- Flickity HTML init -->
<div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "groupCells": 2, "wrapAround": true }'>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
   <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>
```